# using embed inside a java script function

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am having problem in playing mp3 sounds in my website. In a normal page I use an embed tag to play a mp3 file that uses a swf file to play the sound. Now I want to play the sound on a javascript event, eg when a button is pressed, or when user types in a letter. I tried to use a Javascript function that is called when the event occurs, I couldnot figure out how to play a mp3 file using that function. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jwplayer("container").setup({
    file: "/videos/bunny.mp4",
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/jwplayer.swf",
    image: "/thumbs/bunny.jpg",
    height: 270,
    width: 480
  });
</script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().play();">Toggle the playback</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().setMute();">Toggle the audio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="jwplayer().stop();">Stop playback</a></li>
</ul>
```

Read more [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16022/controlling-the-player-using-javascript)